# 正規表現を使った置換でマッチした内容を参照したい。

Tags: python, 正規表現

（タイトルわかりづらくてすいません）
pythonのreモジュールを使用しています。
使いたい場面は今まで何度かありましたが、次のような属性付きのHTMLタグから属性を削除するシチュエーションを考えます。

```
これを
    <div id="hogehoge"><span class="fugafuga">piyopiyo</span></div>

こうしたい
    <div><span>piyopiyo</span></div>
```

現在は`re.sub(<div[^<>]*>, <div>, s)`と、`re.sub(<span[^<>]*>, <span>, s)`の2つの置換で実現していますが、1つの正規表現で書けるのではと考えています。（`s`は上記のHTML文字列です。）

似たような？機能で、`()`で囲んでマッチした部分を`\1, \2`で参照することができるようですが、解決には至りませんでした。
どなたかお知恵を貸してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 似たような？機能で、()で囲んでマッチした部分を\1, \2で参照することができるようですが、解決には至りませんでした。

おっしゃる機能はグループと参照ですね。次のようにすれば、1つの正規表現で（このケースについては）目的を達成できます。

```
s = '<div id="hogehoge"><span class="fugafuga">piyopiyo</span></div>'
s = re.sub(r'<(\w+)[^<>]*>', r'<\1>', s)
print(s) #=> <div><span>piyopiyo</span></div>
```

ただし、HTMLの編集に関しては、正規表現で処理をするのはおすすめしません。このような単純なケースではうまくいくように見えても、複雑なコードではコーナーケースで失敗する可能性が高いです。理想的には、metropolisさんのおっしゃるようにBeautifulSoupやlxmlなどのHTMLのパース・操作を専門とするライブラリを利用した方がよいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

`BeautifulSoup` を利用して属性を削除する方が簡便かと思います。

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div id="hogehoge"><span class="fugafuga">piyopiyo</span></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for elm in soup.find_all():
    elm.attrs.clear()

result = str(soup)
print(result)

# <div><span>piyopiyo</span></div>
```